# Why can't i use this query

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
Dim lstOrderRegels = (From oRR In dbO.orders
                 Join ordreg In dbO.orderregels On oRR.ID Equals ordreg.ordernummer
                 Group Join a In dbO.artikelen On ordreg.artikelID Equals a.ID Into resultArt = Group
                 From art In resultArt.DefaultIfEmpty(New artikelen With {.ID = 0, .subgroep = 0})
                 Group Join subgr In dbO.productsubgroep On art.subgroep Equals subgr.ID Into result = Group
                 From sgr In result.DefaultIfEmpty(New productsubgroep With {.ID = 0, .productgroep_ID = 0})
                 Group Join hgr In dbO.productgroep On sgr.productgroep_ID Equals hgr.ID Into result2 = Group
                 From hg In result2.DefaultIfEmpty(New productgroep With {.ID = 0})
                 Join ses In dbO.sessie On oRR.sessieID Equals ses.ID
                 Where oRR.datum = werkdatum And oRR.status >= 40
                 Order By hg.code, sgr.code).ToList
```

Whenever i run this LINQ i get `Entities cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query`. how can i fix this problem, i can't find any similar solution on google. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes `productgroep` and `productsubgroep`  are generated through the framework, you can't project to *(using New)* to the classes generated through the framework. You have two options either use Anonymous type or create a different class for data transfer and project your result to that class.

Comment: can you give me an example on how this would like with annoymous type? Thank you

Comment: Check [Anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) example would be like `(New With {.ID = 0})`

Comment: I will check the link but when i use 'New With {.ID = 0}' i get a error saying: 'Value of type <annonymous type> can not be converted to 'Entites.productgroep''.

Comment: @Rui, you are trying to create a Default entity , just don't pass any parameter, it would give you an entity with default values. `result.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: The problem with not using parameters is when a article has an id of 0 or Null inside of orderregels table with a price of 10 euros for example, later when im calculating the total of that order those 10 will be missing, because the LINQ query will not return them.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>             Dim lstOrderRegels As New List(Of xRapportDataQuery)
>             Dim lstOrders = (From oRR In dbO.orders
>                              Where oRR.datum = werkdatum And oRR.status >= 40).ToList
>
>             Dim demOrderregels As New List(Of orderregels)
>             For Each OrderData In lstOrders
>                 Dim oregelId As Integer = DMInt(OrderData.ID)
>                 Dim oregel = (From ordr In dbO.orderregels Where ordr.ordernummer = oregelId).ToList
>
>                 If oregel IsNot Nothing Then
>                     For Each item In oregel
>                         demOrderregels.Add(item)
>                     Next
>                 End If
>             Next
>             For Each regelData In demOrderregels
>                 Dim art As artikelen
>                 Dim sgr As productsubgroep
>                 Dim hg As productgroep
>
>                 Dim ordreg As orderregels = regelData
>                 Dim oRR As orders = (From ord In dbO.orders Where ord.ID = regelData.ordernummer).FirstOrDefault
>                 Dim ses As sessie = (From s In dbO.sessie Where s.ID = oRR.sessieID).FirstOrDefault
>                 If DMInt(regelData.artikelID) = 0 Then
>                     art = New artikelen With {.ID = 0, .subgroep = 0}
>                     sgr = New productsubgroep With {.ID = 0, .productgroep_ID = 0}
>                     hg = New productgroep With {.ID = 0}
>                 Else
>                     art = (From a In dbO.artikelen Where a.ID = regelData.artikelID).FirstOrDefault
>                     sgr = (From sg In dbO.productsubgroep Where sg.ID = art.subgroep).FirstOrDefault
>                     hg = (From pg In dbO.productgroep Where pg.ID = sgr.productgroep_ID).FirstOrDefault
>                 End If
>
>
>                 lstOrderRegels.Add(New xRapportDataQuery With {.art = art, .hg = hg, .ordreg = ordreg, .oRR = oRR, .ses = ses, .sgr = sgr})
>             Next
> ```

Ok problem solved, maybe not the best way to do it, but it works and i get no problems.